# Не выводится заголовок и ссылка на дочернюю страницу по ID. WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть главная страница и страница категорий, у которой есть подкатегории. При вставке на главной странице этого кода, выводятся только названия самой Главной страницы в том же количестве, сколько подкатегорий. Нужно чтобы выводил заголовки подкатегорий и ссылок на них. Что не так с этим кодом? 20 - ID страницы, дочерние страницы которой нужно вывести.

```html
<?php 
        $args = array('post_type' => 'page',  'post_parent' => 20, 'orderby' => 'date'); 
        $posts = get_posts($args);
        foreach($posts as $post) { ?>

<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
<div></div>
<div><h4><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h4></div>
</a>

<?php } ?>
```

[image: Вот так получается]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В вашем варианте нужно использовать:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>">
<div></div>
<div><h4><?php echo get_the_title( $post->ID ); ?></h4></div>
</a>
```

Или после открытия цикла `setup_postdata( $post )` и после закрытия цикла `wp_reset_postdata()`

Также вам стоит изучить, как работают циклы в WordPress https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query и станет более понятно, почему главная у вас вывелась несколько раз.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, действительно надо подробнее разобраться.